# Use Custom Function/UDF as "Reducer" in PySpark

Tags: pandas, pyspark, group-by, reduce

```
 Imagine the dataset:

  RequestID  |  RankedItem    | ... more columns ... |
-----------------------------------------------------
RequestID 1  |  RankedItem 11 |
RequestID 1  |  RankedItem 12 |
RequestID 1  |  RankedItem 13 |
RequestID 2  |  RankedItem 21 |
RequestID 2  |  RankedItem 22 |
RequestID 2  |  RankedItem 23 |
```

I want to apply a custom function/UDF on all the rows belonging to the same RequestID.
I need the information from all the rows per RequestID to create a new column per row in that RequestID.

So I want to process and output:

```
  RequestID  |  RankedItem    | ... more columns ... | *new column*
-------------------------------------------------------------
RequestID 1  |  RankedItem 11 |                      | some_value
RequestID 1  |  RankedItem 12 |                      | some_other_value
RequestID 1  |  RankedItem 13 |                      | another_value
```

and output the same number of rows (but also having a new column).

I want to do that for the whole dataset where there are multiple RequestIDs.

How do I do that? I have found `apply` that operates per row, and `groupby` groups the data and I do not need that grouping in the output, I want the original N input rows.

Comment: this depends on what value you want in new column, where the value is from or how it is calculated?  Could you elaborate on how `some_value` is derived?

Comment: each row in an event, `some_value` for a particular row depends on which events happened before and after it; I have to use a for loop to implement this logic, looping through the individual events i.e. all rows for a particular `RequestID`. So I am asking how to call a udf (where this for loop will be) for a set of rows, for the whole table. something like a window function but I am not sure how to write that.

Comment: row-wise loop is the last of last resort in Spark. UDF is okay but less efficient and generally you want to prioritize as Spark operations > UDF >>>> loop. As I am reading your last comment, it is possible to use Spark window functions (but I am not sure yet as it is not clear.) If you can update your input data to be more representative and matching output that you expect from the input, we can better answer your question.